# There's any way to overlay an Image over autocad by holding some key?

Tags: drawing, autocad, cad

I'm Having classes on computational design at university through AutoCad and we are asked to model some drawings. I'd like to know if there's any way to make the image I'm modelling appear on top of the screen while I hold some key, and go back to the model as soon as I release it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such built-in feature in AutoCAD. You can however insert the image in the background. Or you can write your own plugin to do that.

Comment: Thanks mavio, do you have any idea on where to begin writing plugins?

Comment: To write plugins, there are few good choices. Depends on what language you are compfortable with.
A good start point would be using C#. And a good blog to follow is http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/ which you can learn alot from

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use the Attach command to attach your image in AutoCAD
2) Once the image is attached, then you can create your model on top of the image by using the "DR" alias for Draworder and select the image to place on top or behind your model.
3) Select the middle mouse button to Pan around and when you do this, your image file will disappear temporarily until you release your mouse button.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It's a very interesting option wja02, although I wish it did just the other way round. Something like: when I pan around the image appears over the model or something like this.

Comment: If you Attach it as a PDF, then it will pan around showing the image. But if you Attach the image file, like a .JPG, then the image disappears as you pan around. So a PDF file is your best option for viewing your drawing at the same time.